# IOS - Custom segue animation between two controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, segue, uiviewanimation, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to implement a custom segue animation like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptyn84g7fdbthcc/video-1449571130.mp4.mp4?dl=0

right now I am using this code

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func loginScreen(sender: UIButton)
{
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("customSegue", sender: self)
}
```

**CustomSegue.swift**

```
override func perform()
{
let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)

}) { (finished) -> Void in

destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
}
}
```

They are two problems here. first is

obviously this code is not near to the animation like the video I share. I don't know what animation properties should I set to replicate the animation exactly like the video

second problem is

At the end of my segue, the screen flickers as if there is a delay between destination.removeFromSuperview() and source.present...